# Which 'C++ redistributable' is installed as part of .NET framework 3.5 and 4?

Tags: .net, windows, visual-studio, redistributable

i can't find a reference to what 'c++ redistributables' are installed as part of

- .NET Frameworks 3.5
- .NET Frameworks 4

The problem is;
The Customer needs to know which C++ redistributables will be installed on the target machine as a result of our software.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should not rely on any of them being included. If your app relies on a particular version of the CRT, you need to distribute it with the appropriate installer.

Comment: In response to your update, *none* of the C++ redistributables will be installed as a result of your software unless your software specifically installs them. In that case, you will know; you took special effort to make it happen.

Comment: That's what i was used to, but didn't know for sure for the .NET frameworks. Thanks

Comment: I'm not really sure I understand. You marked Hans's answer as "accepted" (green checkmark), but then you edited your question with additional information, suggesting that your question had not really been answered.

Comment: I accepted it, because he explains that even though the framework uses a CRT, it doesn't pollute the windows environment because it's a private dll. Thus the customer doesn't have to worry about it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a redistributable, the framework uses a private copy of the CRT.  It is deployed when you install the framework.  Probably necessary so they can fix their own bugs and security flaws should they arise, independent from the C/C++ distribution.

.NET 2.0 through 3.5 uses msvcr80.dll, a copy of the CRT that started with VS2005.  It is installed in the side-by-side cache, as was common back then, c:\windows\winsxs directory.  Using a .NET specific version number, 8.0.50727.xxxx.  Current xxxx revision number is 9185.

.NET 4.5 and up uses msvcr120_clr0400.dll, a copy of the CRT that started with VS2012.  It is installed in the Windows directory.  I can't remember what 4.0 used.

You can't depend on these DLLs for your own use, the headers and link library are not available.  Nor would that be wise.